# jQuery toggle click

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, jquery-animate

Say I need an element to animate when clicked. To do this I just:

```
$('#header .icon').click(function() {
    $('#header form').animate({width:'195px'});
});
```

But how would I make it so that when I click the element again the opposite animate takes place? (e.g. animate to width: 0px; )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
$('#header .icon').toggle(function() {
  $('#header form').animate({width:'195px'});
}, function() {
  $('#header form').animate({width:'0px'});
});
```

If it was *initially* out you could toggle it's width like this:

```
$('#header .icon').click(function() {
  $('#header form').animate({width:'toggle'});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem today, and none of the answers here solved it for me. My solution was to save states in order to have different things happen when the same element is clicked:

```
var estado="big";
$(".snacks").click(function() {
    if(estado == "big"){
        $("#men_snacks").animate({width:"183px", height:"45px"}, 1000);
        return estado="small";
    } else if(estado == "small") {
        $("#men_snacks").animate({width:"82%",height:"550px"},1000);
        return estado="big";
    }
});
```