# Make div smooth bigger and view other content, toggeling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, smoothing

i have an div called foo. This is the css for the div:

```
background-color: #FFFF00;
float:right;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
```

its in the upper right corner of another div. 
Well if i click on it, i want to change the content SMOOTHLY, and change the size/css SMOOTHLY to this:

```
background-color: #FFFF00;
float: right;
width: 255px;
```

And i want to toggle it... I know its all possible with jQuery, but how? What functions can i use? And what is the best way to do it?

Greetings

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505323/jquery-toggle-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can do it with toggle function and animate, see this example:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   $(".slide").toggle(
    function () {
        $("#slider").animate({marginLeft: "-400px"}, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")
    },
    function () {
        $("#slider").animate({marginLeft: 0}, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")
    }
);});
```

You can change the parameters to fit your needs

Comment: do you have an answer for this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739533/php-curl-is-not-working.